# Is prism used with other gui-frameworks than wpf multiplatform compatible?

Tags: c#, prism, prism-6, avaloniaui

I was wondering if I can use the Prism framwork together with [AvaloniaUI](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI) and if my app would still be multiplatform then.

I only have a windows right now and it works, however, does it work with linux/macOS aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Started creating a port of prism for avalonia, it is still based on perspex, but that shouldnt be a problem. I dont think that it needs a lot of work to get it wotking on avalonia. https://github.com/KeKl/Prism

Comment: Oh cool! If I have time ill look into it/if you want I can help you develop it!

Comment: Sorry get the Mail for a replay right now. Yes of course you can. I think I will update it if a more stable version of avalonia is released

Comment: Alright, maybe give me a heads up once that happens ;)

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, there is [Prism.Avalonia](https://github.com/AvaloniaCommunity/Prism.Avalonia) which is actively maintained supporting the latest Avalonia and Prism packages

Comment: It's been years, but that's good news! Thanks!